# Discord.js rock paper scissors command not doing anything, even though there are no apparent errors

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new to coding, so keep that in mind haha. So basically, I'm trying to create a rock/paper/scissors command for a Discord bot in discord.js. There are no errors, however, when I send the command in Discord, nothing happens. I've successfully done other commands using this same bot and command handler, so I don't know what the issue is. Here's my command handler:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot)return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if(command === 'rps'){
        client.commands.get('rps').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
```

So yeah. Here's the code for my the rps command:

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: "rps",
    description: "play a game of rock, paper and scissors",
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        let embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("RPS")
        .setDescription("React with your choice")
        .setTimestamp()
        let msg = await message.channel.send(embed)
        await msg.react("")
        await msg.react("✂")
        await msg.react("")

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['', '✂', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        }

        const choices = ['', '✂', '']
        const me = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
        msg.awaitReactions(filter, {max:1, time: 60000, error: ["time"]}).then(
            async(collected) => {
                const reaction = collected.first()
                let result = new discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("RESULT")
                .addField("Your choice", `${reaction.emoji.name}`)
                .addField("My choice", `${me}`)
            await msg.edit(result)
                if ((me === "" && reaction.emoji.name === "✂") ||
                (me === "" && reaction.emoji.name === "") ||
                (me === "✂" && reaction.emoji.name === "")) {
                    message.reply("You lost!");
            } else if (me === reaction.emoji.name) {
                return message.reply("It's a tie!");
            } else {
                return message.reply("You won!");
            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
                message.reply('You ran out of time- cancelling game.');
            })
}
}
```

So there it is. There are no error messages, but when I try and run the command, the bot doesn't react. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you so much.

Edit: I didn't include this in the code because im dumb, but I did specify the prefix, so that's not the issue.

Comment: You need to fix your code in the line with `execute` . When you are passing variables in the main you have to pass them with the same order and in command! Then you need to add Discord in variables and fix the `discord.MessageEmbed()` to `Discord.MessageEmbed()`

Answer (score 0):

```
.execute(message, args, Discord);
```

these are the variables you used when you called the function in your main file.
But in the command you use

```
(client, message, args)
```

this might be the reason why it is not working